# Is there a way to make nextjs Image have fixed height and responsive width?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

I want to render an image with a fixed height and have its width be responsive. With a normal image you just set the height and it will respond

```
<img src={image} style={{height: 48}} />
```

I was having trouble achieving this with nextjs Image component. I tried some solutions such as these:

```
<div>
  <Image
    src={image}
    layout="responsive" - only has responsive height
    height={48}
    width={48}
  />
</div>

<div style={{position: "relative"}}> - wasnt responsive and its position was unpredictable
  <Image
    src={image}
    layout="fill"
    objectFit="contain"
    height={48}
  />
</div>
```

Another solution that seemed promising was this but it does not fill the width.

```
.company_logo {
  position: relative !important;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: unset !important;
  height: 48px;
}

.company_image {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.company_image div {
  position: unset !important;
}

<Image
  className={styles.company_image}
  src={image}
  alt=""
  layout="fill"
  quality={100}
  priority
/>
```

I'm playing around with a solution using js where I use an image and a ref with 0 opacity, get the dimensions of the image then set to a basic image with dynamic height and width, which should work fine but I'm assuming there is a much simpler solution to this

```
const imageRef = useRef(),
      [imageDimensions, setImageDimensions] = useState({ height: 0, width: 0 })

useEffect(() => {
  let height = imageRef.current?.naturalHeight,
      width = imageRef.current?.naturalWidth

  setImageDimensions({ height, width })
}, [])

<img ref={imageRef} src={image} style={{opacity: 0}} />

<Image
  src={image}
  height={imageDimensions.height}
  width={imageDimensions.width}
  quality={100}
  priority
/>
```

Comment: What’s wrong with using an `<img>` element? Abstractions are nice if they make your life easier, but don’t let them get in the way.

Comment: @jsejcksn in production i'm just using the img element for that reason. The nextjs images will load with no jump in content and with some other properties like placeholder="blur" theyre just a bit nicer from the UX perspective without me having to write much code. I'll continue to use the img element for now but was curious to see if there was a new solution to this that I had not read about yet

Comment: Maybe you can share more about your use case: raster images have a fixed number of pixels (in both x and y dimensions), so they also have a fixed aspect ratio. Can you explain what you mean when you say that you want "a fixed height, and a _responsive_ width"? (If the height is fixed, then the width should be, too.)

Comment: @jsejcksn the images are uploaded by users so they will have varying dimensions. The desired result is the image is 48px tall and the width maintains the same ratio and the image they uploaded

Comment: FWIW, the Next team appears to be somewhat hostile to the idea of height-specified aspect ratio: issues related to this ([1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/32989), [2](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/22040)) are immediately closed, locked, and transferred to discussion with no further engagement by maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Next doesn't provide an method of declaring only an image's height dimension (so that width will be automatically calculated). This makes sense if layout shift in the x-direction is to be prevented, because, otherwise, it would require Next to load the data for every image in order to determine its intrinsic dimensions before it could calculate the width and respond to the requesting user.

A solution to that would be for you to do it yourself if preventing layout shift is that important to you.

If you pursue this, you can optimize the responses by caching each image's dimensions: because you said that you are storing images uploaded by users, you can calculate each image's intrinsic dimensions when you receive it, and then store the image data *and* its metadata: ID, dimensions, etc. (The ID strategy is up to you, but perhaps it is a hash of the image data.)

Then, when you want to load an image using only a specified height, you can retrieve the dimension metadata for that image and use it to calculate fixed dimensions in your component based on that specified height (using an aspect ratio function). This should be *much* faster than preloading each image in order to determine its dimensions when requested.

---

You can calculate the required dimensions from the intrinsic dimensions like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgWwgOwM5wPZqgXigbQHc4ATYACwC4pkBXBAIwgCcAaKciOAc3OGrqMWAXQDcAKHGhIsRCnRYACswxhUuKAG9xUDl178a9Jswm7iZKkaGnxAXwniAZrWQBjYJmRRuEYPCQ0L1QAMRUEAAl9PigACh0oOGRgZiT0NwD5YOpMoKxUVgTgAENmX2Aonj4BYxZC3RVXEiTuAGUU4uAIbhAAfmoAcjcuABsBqAAfKAGnEYwMZnGpgcbkEgHCgEocuTzsbV03fOACQnZyYQ0klLS4DN2FNDMoI7QTiwoNErK-SoMoABUUEIUAA9Bxnq9UCdvuUAOqkT54VbNZBtDpdHpQXpQACynXI+BRLXazE63RAwliH3Imyg1Bpz2YflozG8+FhfgRlnYnIq0WAYnskhc7k8WCgxVQylU6liRER5HOAuEO0Cj1Q21k6q8MrUWgSzOArO8mhpyqqwAcwskoPBAFVUBBKJIoSczYqLQY7BopXrULFyrkNWEMJEBfKAIwATgATAAGdiR+MADnjwnYABYU5tNo5xHaoAAVCDQ1Au5yuDxeSWoJ3MYAAUQAjrRiiN1AAeIsAPlixQ8bZG1CL7AgAA9IB4ICQR1qAG4YUgG3RwJxxAfG9tQACEODwE6nXRIdIOuigFBUIOQEBBjeYKmYsQABgA1du0Us0DAnCCt9sADrII2k4QNOs5QAAJJoh5gcedhAQASmBXDzjO1DQZuQ52M+eYJHYNpuokySpEEbhqlk+QaPgMYJkmqbphIRF8n8MR4NmjiitWErwoqcTEmipLkj0-RQIopTFEgXTMKgnbSBAGDrkGDzBKG4aWj2+CxsIp6GiybI+H4waqeErHALE1ykekvKlOUZnsAJ6JkpiICbPgjE2lK9ZNv+HaBlyiqxJs7CxCmACsUAANRxJGYJQAAzLmeFeSwPlDgGvGWLEKwYE0AzBVA4XJXWqUtul-nANyFDZbM8yLAVRUSClDZle2GUBVlQyjPl7ApgAbHhUIYCMEAAHRzNw2UAPIANY7vlEhAA)

```ts
type Dimensions = [width: number, height: number];

type DimensionProps = {
  height: number;
  width: number;
};

function getDimensionsFromHeight (
  intrinsicDimensions: Dimensions,
  targetHeight: number,
  roundingStrategy?: 'ceil' | 'floor' | 'round',
): Dimensions {
  const [w, h] = intrinsicDimensions;
  const width = targetHeight * w / h;
  const targetWidth = roundingStrategy ? Math[roundingStrategy](width) : width;
  return [targetWidth, targetHeight];
}

function asProps ([width, height]: Dimensions): DimensionProps {
  return {width, height};
}


// Use:

const {width, height} = asProps(getDimensionsFromHeight([1920, 1080], 48));
```